# Overwrite payload in the logs inside catchexceptionstrategy

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el

I have enabled "Log Exceptions" in case of below catch-exception-strategy. I am setting the payload here but still in the logs original payload is getting printed. How can i intercept that and set it to value from Flow variable. Below is my catch-exception-strategy and log message. I want to do this for any runtime exception. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
 <catch-exception-strategy  doc:name="500">
        <message-properties-transformer doc:name="Message Properties">
                <add-message-property key="http.status" value="500"/>
                <add-message-property key="Content-Type" value="application/json"/>
            </message-properties-transformer>
            <set-payload value="#[flowVars.maskedCCPayloadVar]" mimeType="application/json" doc:name="Set maskedCCPayloadVar"/>
 </catch-exception-strategy>
```

Log message

org.mule.exception.CatchMessagingExceptionStrategy:

---

```
Message               : Execution of the expression "payload/test" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException).
Payload               : {
  "Request": {
    "CardDetails": {     
      "CardNumber": "5123456789012346",
      "ExpiryDate": "0521"
    },
    "AccountId": "12345678"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log exception will log the exception that caused the catch exception strategy to be invoked

If you want to log something else in the logs you can use a Logger message processor for example `<logger message="Error message #[exception.getMessage()] level="ERROR" />` from within your exception strategy block. Furthermore, if you want to suppress the default error log in mule you can disable the "Log Exceptions" on the catch exception strategy block.

Answer (score 0):

Use setpayload component or dataweave to set payload within your catch exception strategy.